# Bamboo rest api fetching current or latest build

Tags: bamboo

Is there a rest call for bamboo that'll allow me to fetching if not the current build, then the latest build stats?

```
 /result/{projectKey}-{buildKey}/{buildNumber : ([0-9]+)|(latest)}?expand&favourite&start-index&max-results
```

This gets the most recent complete build and it's not really what I'm after. I want to get the current build, and if it's not building, then return the latest complete.

In Jenkins you've got the below which does what I'm after

```
/lastBuild/api/json
```

I'm after the bamboo equivalent. Bamboo's documentation is pretty poor...